# How to skip defined getters or setters in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter

In java you can do the follwing:

```java
public class Foo {

    private String bar = "text";

    public void method() {
        // direct access (no logic)
        System.out.println(this.bar);
    }

    // only if you access the object from the outside
    // you are forced to use the getter with some logic in it
    public String getBar() {
        System.out.println(this.bar);
        return this.bar;
    }

}
```

But if you define a getter or a setter with logic in Kotlin you are forced to always execute this logic when accessing the field:

```kotlin
class Foo {

    var bar: String = "text"
        get() {
            println(field)
            return field
        }
        private set

    fun method() {
        // this also executes the getter
        // Is it possible to skip the getter
        // and directly access the field?
        println(this.bar)
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to access the field without executing the getter or setter logic than creating your own `fun getBar()` in Kotlin?

Comment: Instead of using Kotlin's getter and setter, create methods for them to use the methods..Getters will always work anytime you get

Comment: @JosteveAdekanbi So I really have to create a `fun getBar()` like in the last sentence in order to make the logic optional?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: @bluefireoly, no getBar() are always called when you access the variable, the get() actually gets translated to getBar() at compilation.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu So do I even have to choose a different method name?

Comment: Yep, because getters and setters are intended to block the direct access of a property even in java you usually create private properties and provide custom getters and setters for interception in between. But since there is open structure in java you can access it directly.

Comment: @AnimeshSahu In game development you often want to provide access with some logic to the outside, but access a field without a function call inside of the class. It doesn't seem to be optimized for this type of use case.

Comment: @bluefireoly so for that case you can make a fake reference.

Comment: In that case (which IME isn't that common) I think people often have a private property called `_field`, and then a public property `field` with its own getter (which uses `_field` instead of its own backing field).  You can replace the latter with a `getField()` method, especially if it has significant side-effects.

Comment: yep that's what i mean by fake references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no possible way to skip a getter or a setter, they are intended to block the direct access of a property.

What you can do is make a multi-reference to same value (fake-referencing):

```kotlin
private var _bar: String = "text"
var bar
    get() {
        // some operations intercepting the getter
        return _bar
    }

// direct access
_bar
// intercepted access public field
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin the backing fields (in your case the private variable) are not exposed by design. There are a few exceptions explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields

All access to `val` and `var` happens through implicit getters and setters. A `val` resolves to a property with a getter() while `var` resolves to a property with a getter and a setter: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#properties-and-fields